# Wildfly CLI - disable environment variable resolution? i.e. write unresolved variable to config

Tags: jboss, docker, command-line-interface, wildfly

I'm trying to modify the config of a running Wildfly (inside Docker) using the JBoss CLI. One thing I need to do is

```
data-source add --connection-url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}:3306/xplore (...)
```

I need the resulting config in standalone.xml to literally contain

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}:3306/xplore</connection-url>
```

DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR is a variable that will be resolved by Wildfly when it's rebooted. It does not exist when I'm CLI-ing.

The problem is that CLI attempts to resolve it (and fails) during my CLI session (instead of injecting it as a plain string), resulting in output like errors and even

```
<connection-url>$</connection-url>
```

I've tried to work around this by adding "..." and '...', escaping the $ to \$, removing the brackets, and defining a variable containing my string in the script and inserting that variable (*still* gets resolved). I've looked up the docs on this, and while there is a command resolve-expression(), there is no inverse, no setting for it, nothing. It doesn't seem possible to prevent the resolution from happening.

How can I insert an unresolved expression into my config via the CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to issue this command:

```
data-source add --connection-url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR:}:3306/xplore (...)
```

With a : after ADDR. This obviously solves the resolution error since it will now default to an empty value, and somehow it actually causes the string value itself to be written. It also turns out it wasn't the CLI that was resolving my variable, but the server itself.

---

The real solution though was to stop the session, modify the server settings and disable variable resolution entirely, then start a new session.

Comment: well, that should be ${env.DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR} and it would work just fine without any workarounds.

Comment: @ctomc nope, that would fail with '"WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${env.DB_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}'".
Marnes, how do you disable variable resolution in the server config?

Comment: The variable resolution is actually disabled by default. It's configured in via the "resolve-parameter-values" property in the file "../bin/wildfly-cli.xml".